# Schengen visa application in Romania

Tags: schengen-visas, romania

I'm going to be an Erasmus student in Romania and i do not have a schengen visa but i'd love to get it for travelling all around the Europe. my question is that is it possible to get an schengen visa during my student mobility in Romania for some EU countries that are included to the schengen area?If yes, How? Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, yes. You will have to convince the visa officials that you can afford the trip, that you are actually coming for tourism, and that you will leave the Schengen area again.

- Your Erasmus program might help to convince people that you want to return to *Romania*. Make sure that your tourism does not interfere with your studies.
- You should have a clear idea what you want to do in the Schengen area and how much it will cost you. It should be an amount that is credible for sightseeing purposes. You will have to document the source of the funds.